# Find and replace using wildcard in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column in Power BI that contains difference Operating System such as Windows 7 Professional and Windows 7 Home "etc" I would like to just have them show Windows 7. I thought using the find and replace searching for Windows 7* and replace with Windows 7 would work but it seems that Power BI does not recognize the * unless I am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in the GUI. I recommend adding your support for this idea to increase the likelihood of Microsoft implementing it:

[Ability to use wildcards in power query transformation find section of replace values](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7234097-ability-to-use-wildcards-in-power-query-transforma)

---

In the meantime, you can do a workaround using the `Text.Contains` function.

Here is an example from [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc1aceb5-a1b1-49ee-82fe-bd421e067920/power-query-findreplace-values-using-wildcard-string?forum=powerquery):

```
let
    inputString = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="InputString"]}[Content][Column1]{0},

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Modified Values", each [Values]),
    replaceTextIfContains = (inputText, old, new) =>

    if (inputText is text and Text.Contains(inputText, old)) then
            new
        else
            inputText,

    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom",inputString ,inputString,  replaceTextIfContains,{"Modified Values"})
in
    #"Replaced Value
```